# Recursion Palindrome

Tags: c, recursion

We are given a string of 7 characters long and we are required to print out every possible palindrome of this string that accomplish specific requirements

The first and seventh characters are the same small letter (a, ..., z).

The second and sixth characters are the same capital letter (A, ..., Z).

The third and fifth characters are the same digit (0, ..., 9).

The fourth character is always a '-' or a '+' character

For example, passwords `aA1-1Aa`, `cZ9+9Zc`, and `fL0+0Lf` are acceptable, whereas `aA1+1Ab` is not

I only want to ask this not the entire exercise.

I have done a similar in a way exercise called magic matrix where the sum of every row and every column and every diagonal is equal. But in there its easy because you start with n=1 then you simply increase it.

What i want to ask is.

How do i do it so that for example I first start with a......a then lets say +1 and then we have b......b. How do i do the equivalent of +1 but for characters and how do i initialize it.

This is all i ask.

Is the question clear?

Comment: In C, you can add one to a char, since a char is just a byte, a number on 8 bits. Starting with `char c = 'a';` then you do `c++;` to get `c == 'b'`. As simple as that. (Letters are just numbers,  `A` is conventionally represented by the number 65, for instance)

Comment: Look up on ASCII tables if you want to know which number corresponds with which character

Comment: @Déjàvu Its 4 am over here and it hit me like a brick 2 min after i wrote it here. So embarassed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out (in ASCII) to get to the next character, you add one. `'a' + 1 == 'b'`. So `for (int ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++) ...`.